# Ember.js input fields

Tags: input, ember.js

Is it possible to use standard HTML5 input fields in an Ember.js view, or are you forced to use the limited selection of built in fields like Ember.TextField, Ember.CheckBox, Ember.TextArea, and Ember.select? I can't seem to figure out how to bind the input values to the views without using the built in views like:

```
Input: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="objectValue" }}
```

Specifically, I'm in need of a numeric field. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**EDIT:** This is now out of date you can achieve everything above with the following:

`{{input value=objectValue type="number" min="2"}}`

---

#### Outdated answer

You can just specify the type for a TextField

```
Input: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="objectValue" type="number"}}
```

If you want to access the extra attributes of a number field, you can just subclass `Ember.TextField`.

```
App.NumberField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  type: 'number',
  attributeBindings: ['min', 'max', 'step']
})

Input: {{view App.NumberField valueBinding="objectValue" min="1"}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Ember, I hope you enjoy your stay.

Comment: Good lord, it works. I'd marry Ember.js if she came with better documentation.

Comment: I'd love to hear what you can't find in the documentation, personally I think the documentation is pretty good these days, if there's something missing, I'll add it myself

Comment: And I'm going to assume you're not married yet if you're expecting it to come with documentation :)

Comment: Nope, single, thats why I'm vying for Ember love. You're right, the documentation is pretty good, I'll let you know though if I can think of something that needs more doc. Thanks!

Comment: We're always looking to improve out documentation. Although, humorously, this functionality _is_ documented: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html under the heading "HTML Attributes"

Comment: it's actually not sending a number into the controller, but a string (which is a little bit ironic when you have defined a min, a max or a step).

Comment: How would you set the starting value of the input field? For example, the equivalent of : <input type='number' value='10'>     Adding 'value' to the App.NumberField attributeBindings does not seem to work like it does for step, min, and max.

Comment: @koanima that's becaused value is a computed property inside Ember.TextField, if you're manually setting the value on an input there's no need to use App.NumberField at all just put the <input on the page. More likely you need to give a default value to the context object backing the input than anything else

Comment: @BradleyPriest Thanks. I was trying to pre-load a default value as a placeholder. It was in a component, so I added like this: App.ObjectDetailComponent = Ember.Component.extend({placeHolderValue: 10});  Then in the component template, like this: {{view App.NumberField value=placeHolderValue valueBinding='adjustFactor'}}    The problem is that although the value displays in the number field, it gets submitted as NaN. Any ideas?

Comment: I think that the right way to do the first part is now `Input: {{input valueBinding="objectValue" type="number"}}` ... I would edit but I don't feel comfortable with that as I'm somewhat new to ember myself.

Comment: The provided version is actually the correct version, although both will work. If you provide a value in a view helper without wrapping it in quotation marks it is treated as a binding. So `valueBinding="objectValue"` and `value=objectValue` produce the same output

Answer (score 4):

@Bradley Priest's answer above is correct, adding type=number does work. I found out however that you need to add some attributes to the Ember.TextField object if you need decimal numbers input or want to specify min/max input values. I just extended Ember.TextField to add some attributes to the field:

```
//Add a number field
App.NumberField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['name', 'min', 'max', 'step']
});
```

In the template:

```
{{view App.NumberField type="number" valueBinding="view.myValue" min="0.0" max="1.0" step="0.01" }}
```

et voile!

Answer (score 4):

Here is my well typed take on it :

```
    App.NumberField = Ember.TextField.extend({
        type: 'number',
        attributeBindings: ['min', 'max', 'step'],
        numericValue: function (key, v) {
            if (arguments.length === 1)
                return parseFloat(this.get('value'));
            else
                this.set('value', v !== undefined ? v+'' : '');
        }.property('value')
    });
```

I use it that way:

```
{{view App.NumberField type="number" numericValueBinding="prop" min="0.0" max="1.0" step="0.01" }}
```

The other systems where propagating strings into number typed fields.

Answer (score 1):

You may also wish to prevent people from typing any old letters in there:

```
App.NumberField = App.TextField.extend({
  type: 'number',
  attributeBindings: ['min', 'max', 'step'],
  numbericValue : function (key,v) {
    if (arguments.length === 1)
      return parseFloat(this.get('value'));
    else
      this.set('value', v !== undefined ? v+'' : '');
  }.property('value'),
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().keypress(function(key) {
      if((key.charCode!=46)&&(key.charCode!=45)&&(key.charCode < 48 || key.charCode > 57)) return false;
    })  
  }
})
```

Credit where its due: I extended nraynaud's answer

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do this now (currently Ember 1.6-beta5) using components (using the ideas from @nraynaud & @nont):

```
App.NumberFieldComponent = Ember.TextField.extend
  tagName: "input"
  type: "number"

  numericValue: ((key, value) ->
    if arguments.length is 1
      parseFloat @get "value"
    else
      @set "value", (if value isnt undefined then "#{value}" else "")
  ).property "value"

  didInsertElement: ->
    @$().keypress (key) ->
      false  if (key.charCode isnt 46) and (key.charCode isnt 45) and (key.charCode < 48 or key.charCode > 57)
```

Then, to include it in a template:

```
number-field numericValue=someProperty
```