# How to override a parent property in ember.js? (Specifically number input's behaviour)

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

I want to write a new component that extends Ember Input as number input. When users of this class binds their values to `value` property of *number-input-component*, they should only get a number (or NaN for invalid values). In Ember Input, value has an attribute binding.

I've defined a computed property named "value" on *number-input-component* as following:

```
value:Ember.computed({
    get:function(key){
       let htmlValue = this.get('htmlvalue');
       return this.sanitize(htmlValue);
    },
    set:function (key, htmlvalue){
       this.set('htmlvalue', htmlvalue);

       if(this.get('onUpdate')) {
          this.get('onUpdate')(this.sanitize(htmlvalue));
       }
       return this.sanitize(htmlvalue);
    }
}),
```

It works as expected but it's not working in two-way binding. (Actually it is ok for DDAU. But it should work in two-way bindings.)

*Note*:
I know that I can supply another property such as "numericValue" (shown as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17257258/4545506)) so that users can bind their values to "numericValue". But I don't want to confuse users with both *value* and *numericValue*.

**UPDATE:**

While typing to the field, any typo shouldn't reset the value. For example while user is trying to write "123456789" and accidentally press "12345678p" should not cause the input reset. Neither displaying an error message nor reseting the value is not a responsibility of the component when value is invalid.

There is a fiddle you can see: [Ember-Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/387bd1dc7106ff46673902df942d1b8b?openFiles=components.number-input.js%2C)

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to overwrite the `_elementValueDidChange()` method. You can get the current DOM value by `this.readDOMAttr('value')`, do your sanitizing and finally call `this.set('value', sanitizedValue)`. This is how Ember internally changes the `value` property.

Comment: Yes, doing like that can completely solve the problem. But I'm not confident with that because of underscore. Is it somehow private/non-reliable function?

Comment: It is private yes, but because we are overwriting the default behaviour of a input component I don't think it's a bad thing. I'm using something similar in my app, never had any trouble with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an observer of the `value` property and when it is changed, replace it with the sanitized version:

```
valueWatcher() {
    this.set('value' this.sanitize(this.get('value')));
}.observes('value')
```

Ember will prevent the race condition when an observer modifies the property it watches.

Comment: But it is flickering while typing in field. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution using `_elementDidChange` suggested in @jcbvm's solution. Also override attributeBindings to manage the screen value.

Here it is:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.TextField.extend({
  type:'text',//hey! this is text!

  init(){
    this._super(...arguments);
    let arr = this.get('attributeBindings');
    arr.removeObject('value');
    arr.pushObject('val:value');
  },

  val: Ember.computed('domValue', 'value', function() {
    let value = this.get('value');
    //detect whether the update is trigger by dom or by users of this class:
    if(!Number.isNaN(value) && this.sanitize(this.get('domValue')) !== value){
      return value;
    }
    return this.get('domValue');
  }),

  _elementValueDidChange(){
    let domValue = this.readDOMAttr('value');
    let value = this.sanitize(domValue);
    if(this.sanitize(this.get('domValue')) !== value){
        this.set('domValue', domValue);      
    }
    this.set('value', value);
  },


  sanitize:function(value){
    if(value === ''){
      return Number.NaN;
    }
    return Number(value);
  }
});
```

The reason of using `type=text` is html5 number inputs' sanitization algorithm. `input type=number` component returns empty string for invalid values on Chrome, Firefox and Edge (not IE).Reference for sanitization [from W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/the-input-element.html#value-sanitization-algorithm).

Cons of this solution:

- Overrides `_elementDidChange`
- Modifies attributeBindings. (Maybe parent classes depends on this value.)