# How to invalidate `<input>`s internal state?

Tags: ember.js

Assume I have a simple input in `ember.js`:

```
<input value={{val}} />
```

And then enter text there. How can I enforce ember to reset the `<input>` *to the same value* with code?

A simple `this.notifyPropertyChange('val');` or `set(this, 'val', get(this, 'val'));` does *not* work.

You have to do something like this:

```
let oldVal = get(this, 'val');
set(this, 'val', 'some dummy value');
Ember.run.later(() => set(this, 'val', oldVal));
```

But thats really hacky.

---

Let me explain why I need this. One example is an input where the user may only enter the letters `A` and `B`, but not `C`. It would be nice to do something like this:

*hbs*:

```
<input value={{val}} oninput={{action 'update' value='target.value'}} />
```

*js*:

```
val: '',
actions: {
    update(newVal) {
        if(!newVal.includes('C')) {
            set(this, 'val', newVal);
        } else {
            // reset the input to the last valid value.
            // so basically do
            set(this, 'val', get(this, 'val'));
            // or
            this.notifyPropertyChange('val');
            // but neither does update the <input>.
            // the only way is this:
            let oldVal = get(this, 'val');
            set(this, 'val', 'some dummy value');
            Ember.run.later(() => set(this, 'val', oldVal));
            // because this enforces the <input> to forget its internal state.
            // is there any other way to do this?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should user the {{input}} helper. It'll take care of all this for you. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_input

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 not if I want to use DDAU. And the `{{action}}` helper has the same problem if you bind it to a computed property and change the value in the setter.

Comment: @Lux Did you look at [ember-one-way-controls](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-one-way-controls) addon?

Comment: @ykaragol I've considered that, but I'm pretty sure they have the same problem tho.

Answer (score 1):

I found two different ways to do this:

1. Reset dom value to previous value at action listener. (If I'm not wrong, that's way ember-one-way-controls does. Have a look at this addon's code.)
2. Handle keyPress, keyDown or keyUp functions and return false if input is invalid. (That is the js way.)

I've implemented the second choice at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/7f4734fe84fd85b96f1f969034c002c3?openFiles=components.my-input.js%2C). You can change the `sanitize` function with your rules.

You can see [previous discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941190/how-to-override-a-parent-property-in-ember-js-specifically-number-inputs-beha) about number input component (maybe related but different).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you, but in any case I will throw it to you. If this was my problem, this is how I will approached. Also just note that I am using a dinosaurs version of ember(1.3)

```
{{input value=val action="createNote"}}

textChanged: function(){

 if(!newValue.includes('C')) {
        //whatever you want 
    } else {

    }
}.observes("newValue"),

  actions: {
    updateValue: function(){
      this.set('newValue', val);
    } 

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change internal state of `val` property, then you have to leave `val` property as its and update `val` in DOM element by yourself. (Note: setting the same value will not trigger rerender). [Ember-Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/879003a723f0fab14d1fcbf8f0836d29?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)

**components/my-component.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
const {get,set} = Ember;

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  val:'',
  actions:{
    update(newVal){      
      let oldVal = get(this, 'val');      
      console.log('newVal-',newVal+' oldVal-',oldVal);
      if(!newVal.includes('C')) {
            set(this, 'val', newVal);
        } else {          
          this.$('#fieldId').val(oldVal);
        }
    }
  }
});
```

**templates/components/my-component.hbs**

```
<input id='fieldId' name='fieldName' value={{val}} oninput={{action 'update' value='target.value'}} />
{{val}}
{{yield}}
```

**templates/application.hbs**

```
{{my-component }}
```

Comment: you essentially use `newVal` as the dummy value. If you use `Ember.run.later(...)` or `Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', ...)` does not make any difference.

Comment: Now I understand complexity in the question.

Comment: @Lux manually updating the input DOM element to oldVal. that's only way to go AFAIK.